# Quasar framework, select filtering strange behaviour

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using Quasar q-select component with filtering. When I start entering the term it is duplicating as per the image shows:

[image]

My setup is as follows. "options" is an object having "id" and "name" fields.

```
<q-select
    filled
    v-model="chosenPartner"
    input-debounce="0"
    option-value="id"
    option-label="name"
    use-input
    label="Partner"
    :options="options"
    @filter="filterFn"
    style="width: 250px"
>
    <template v-slot:no-option>
        <q-item>
            <q-item-section class="text-grey"> No item </q-item-section>
        </q-item>
    </template>
</q-select>
```

On the quasar document page, the select works as expected, however I am following the documentation.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: what is filterFn

Comment: Please post the minimum amount of code capable of reproducing the problem.  Using your code + similar code to the docs [this was my best attempt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-nrcsdi?file=src%2Flayouts%2FMainLayout.vue,src%2Fpages%2FIndexPage.vue), but it works fine, and I'm not able to reproduce.